# Куки,таймер,событие

Tags: таймер, события

Приветствую! Хотел реализовать на сайте таймер с куки:Случайный посетитель нажимает на кнопку, происходит к примеру изменение цвета background, запускается таймер на 1 час и после выхода из страницы, в куки пользователя сохраняется сколько времени останется до следующего нажатия на кнопку. Заранее спасибо за помощь! :)

Comment: Покажите что вы пробовали, и что не получилось?

Comment: Нельзя доверять браузеру, куки можно отчистить и все дела.

Comment: @And ну можно конечно через базу сохранять данные о человеке и запоминать, но не охота ,не ужели через куки никак?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев  я не говорил , что пробовал, я искал разные таймера, но тот который мне нужен не нашел и обратился за помощью сюда

Comment: @HolyDi Что значит "искал разные таймера". Таймер существует только один, функция `setTimeout()`. в момент старта таймера сохраняете ожидаемое время завершения. Если страницу закрыли и отрыли заново смотрите сохраненное время - если оно больше текущего - вычисляете остаток и на него делаете setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Вот. Думаю, разберётесь.

```js
var TIMEOUT = 15; // sec

function showTime(t) {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (t != 0) ? t : "";
}

function timer(t) {
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    if (t == undefined)
        t = TIMEOUT;
    showTime(t);
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        --t;
        showTime(t);
        if (t <= 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function onClick() {
    document.cookie = "timeout=" + new Date();
    timer();
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(
        new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)")
    );
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}

function onLoad() {
    var prevStartTime = new Date(getCookie("timeout"));
    var delta = TIMEOUT - Math.round((new Date() - prevStartTime) / 1000);
    if (delta > 0) {
        timer(delta);
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoad();">
    <button id="btn" onclick="onClick();">Click me!</button>
    <br />
    <span id="time"></span>
</body>
```

Подробнее про куки [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie). Там же и украл функцию `getCookie`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает! А можешь подсказать, как сделать событие после того как таймер закончиться, к примеру изменение цвета background в js? Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: В функции `timer` присутствует оператор `if (t <= 0)`, тело этого `if` выполняется после того, как время таймера истечёт. Там можно выполнять любые действия, в том числе и смену фона командой вида `document.body.style.background = "yellow"`.

Comment: да я уже сообразил, поспешил с вопросом и забыл указать, что а если для уникального блока с id?

Comment: `document.getElementById("идентификатор").style.background = "yellow"`